# Windows 10 - WPF window resize redraw bug

Tags: windows, windows-10, wpf

On my Windows 10 machine (came with Win10 from the factory, currently running build 14393.447), applications written using Windows Presentation Foundation (including Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 RC, as well as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), which is shown below) do not correctly redraw their window contents. In ILSpy, this occurs when clicking the maximize/restore button. In Visual Studio, this bug manifests as the user interface not being redrawn in a timely fashion, which results in unclickable "remnants" of UI elements that have recently appeared or disappeared remaining on the screen. I have provided a few screenshots below.

This only occurs on my specific Windows 10 laptop. Tests using ILSpy in an otherwise-untouched Windows 8.1 VM do not exhibit this bug. In addition, I have not seen any indication that this bug has affected any other user in my Google searches. (Besides, because it impacts usability so greatly, if someone else did encounter this bug, it should have been fixed by now; this issue has been dogging me for months.)

[image: WPF bug example #1]
[image: WPF bug example #2]
[image: WPF bug example #3]
[image: WPF bug example #4]

Comment: update the GPU driver

Comment: @magicandre1981: I just updated the GPU driver, and the bug still occurs (tested with ILSpy).

Comment: which hardware do you use?

Comment: +1. After installing VS2017 a few days ago I've also noticed that redraw fails on window resize in many Windows 10 applications, such as Microsoft's Mail (Version 17.8126.42377.0). When this bug appears at some point it seems to affects all UWP apps, but goes away after a reboot until the next time. Video drivers update doesn't help.